# Adjectives in the introductory there structure can come after nouns?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, word-order, formal-language, postpositive-adjectives

I have seen in some grammar book the following pattern, which allows to place an adjective after a noun:

> A shelf is empty.
>
> ➔ There is a shelf empty.

I want to know whether the above pattern is a general rule for the introductory there (if so, please also mention the reason because we do not have such a thing in similar structures; for example, we do not say "it is a book good") so that we can have similar examples like

"there is a man nice",

or it only applies to some certain class of adjectives (including "empty")?

Comment: It's definitely not a general rule - none of your examples except the one you quoted seem natural. The reasons are... [complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective#In_modern_English), and it doesn't seem like there's a single rule.

Comment: Note that _A shelf is empty,_ the initial sentence, is grammatical; so is its transform, _There is a shelf empty._ But the sentence *_A man is nice_ does not refer to a specific man, and therefore _there_-insertion can't apply to it.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks for your comment, which is in fact the answer to my post. So, if I understood correctly, when we attribute an adjective to a **specific** noun, for example, in the form of "a [noun] is [adjective]", we can **always** place the adjective after the noun in an introductory there structure, and this case is **the only** one in which an adjective follows a noun in an introductory there structure, right?

Comment: ... , and this case is **the only** one in which a non-postpositive adjective follows a noun in an introductory there structure, right?

Comment: @Later No, that's not what I meant, so you must have understood incorrectly. The adjective placement is a result of_there_-insertion, which moves the subject. The predicate adjective stays where it is. The point is that if the subject of a sentence is not a specific referent, then _there_-insertion can't apply, even if the clause meets the requirements otherwise. It has nothing to do with adjective placement. And I never mentioned **all** or **only** anything. Those are very dangerous words for syntacticians to use, and if you heard me saying them then you may not quote me.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, you are right; I understood your point incorrectly. Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: "some book..."  ***What book!!***